# What is the Right Permission For Magneto 2.4 on CentOS 7 Lampp

Tags: php, magento, centos7, linode

I am using Linode with CentOS 7 Magneto 2.4 on XAMPP. I have tried various permission sets but finally got this issues. Please suggest right permission.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/var/page_cache" is not writable in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/opt...') #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array) #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true) #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(158): Zend_Cache::factory('Magento\\Framewo...', 'Cm_Cache_Backen in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php on line 209
```

Comment: 2.4 ? 2.3 not even released 
but you probably need to set folder ownership, if permission is correct
set web user as owner of folder

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/var/cache/" is not writable in /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209 Stack trace: #0

Answer (score 0):

The correct permissions when using CentOS 7 Magneto 2.4 on XAMPP.
Would be to grant all magento dirrecty apache user and group.

That can be achieved by running

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /opt/lampp/htdocs/magento/
```

Remeber to add your user into apache group, if you desire to run commands, such as cache clear or reindexing.

It can be easly done by running following command

```
sudo usermod -a -G apache $USER
```

Instance restart will be required for permissions to apply

And finally apply permissions, by running

```
find app/code var/view_preprocessed vendor pub/static app/etc generated/code generated/metadata \( -type f -or -type d \) -exec chmod u-w {} + && chmod o-rwx app/etc/env.php
```

You can read more info on [Adobe's site](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/deployment/file-system-permissions.html)